# Wrong display of properties under component

Tags: delphi, components

I would like to create a component with the structure as bellow:

```
type
  TCustomMyComp = class;
  TMyComp = class;
  TCustomSqlCommands = class;
  TSqlCommands = class;
  TFields = class;
  TFieldsItem = class;
  TFieldsSqlCommands = class;

 TCustomMyComp = class(TComponent)
  private
    FFields: TFields;
    FSqlCommands: TSqlCommands;
    procedure SetFields(Value: TFields);
    procedure SetSqlCommands(Value: TSqlCommands);
    procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Fields: TFields read FFields write SetFields;
    property SqlCommands: TSqlCommands read FSqlCommands write SetSqlCommands;
  end;

TCustomSqlCommands = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FOwner: TCustomMyComp;
    FSelect: TStrings;
    FInsert: TStrings;
    FUpdate: TStrings;
    FDelete: TStrings;
    procedure SetSql(Index: Integer; Value: TStrings);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TCustomMyComp); virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  published
    property Select: TStrings index 0 read FSelect write SetSql;
    property Insert: TStrings index 1 read FInsert write SetSql;
    property Update: TStrings index 2 read FUpdate write SetSql;
    property Delete: TStrings index 3 read FDelete write SetSql;
  end;

[ComponentPlatformsAttribute(pidWin32 or pidWin64)]
  TMyComp = class(TCustomMyComp)
  published
    property Fields;
    property SqlCommands;
  end;

TSqlCommands = class(TCustomSqlCommands)
  published
    property Insert;
    property Update;
    property Delete;
  end;

//------- Fields -----------

  TFields = class(TCollection)
  private
    FOwner: TCustomMyComp;
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): TFieldsItem;
    procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; Value: TFieldsItem);
  protected
    function GetOwner: TPersistent; override;
    procedure Update(Item: TCollectionItem); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TCustomMyComp);
    function Add: TFieldsItem;
    function Owner: TCustomMyComp;
  end;

  TFieldsItem = class(TCollectionItem)
  private
    FOwner: TCustomMyComp;
    FSqlCommands: TFieldsSqlCommands;
    procedure SetSqlCommands(Value: TFieldsSqlCommands);
  protected
    function GetDisplayName: String; override;
    procedure SetIndex(Value: Integer);  override;
  public
    constructor Create(Collection: TCollection); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  published
    property SqlCommands: TFieldsSqlCommands read FSqlCommands write SetSqlCommands;
  end;

  TFieldsSqlCommands = class(TCustomSqlCommands)
  published
    property Select;
    property Insert;
  end;
```

I face 2 issues:

1. Property `SqlCommands: TSqlCommands` contain all properties that were defined under `TCustomSqlCommands` even I defined to published only `Insert,Update,Delete`.
2. Property `Fileds->SqlCommands: TFieldsSqlCommands` contain NO properties  even I defined to published only `Select,Insert`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The typical design pattern is to have a `TCustom...` class define its properties as either `public` or `protected`, but never as `published`.  This way, a derived class can decide which properties it wants to promote to `published` as needed.  This would allow `TSqlCommands` to not publish the `Select` property, and `TFieldsSqlCommands` to not publish the `Update` and `Delete` properties.
2. Your `Fields` property is a `TFields` object (BTW, the VCL already has a `TFields` class in the `DB` unit, so you should consider renaming your class to something more unique).  Your `TFields` class does not have an `SqlCommands` property, it is a property of `TFieldsItem` instead.  So you need to access one of your field items in order to reach its `SqlCommands` property.

   However, although `TFields` is a collection of `TFieldsItem` objects, you have not declared a property to expose *direct* access to your `TFieldsItem` object pointers (although you have declared getter/setter methods for such a property).  You are inheriting the base `Items[]` property from `TCollection`, and that property exposes `TCollectionItem` object pointers, which you would have to type-cast to `TFieldItem`.  So, you should add your own property (name it whatever you want) to your `TFields` class to handle that type-casting:

   ```
   TFields = class(TCollection)
   private
     ...
     function GetField(Index: Integer): TFieldsItem;
     procedure SetField(Index: Integer; Value: TFieldsItem);
     ...
   public
     ...
     property Fields[Index: Integer]: TFieldsItem read GetField write SetField default;
   end;
   ```

   BTW, since `TFields` has an `Owner`, you should consider deriving it from `TOwnedCollection` instead of `TCollection` directly.

Comment: Yes, it's working now! It's logic also... Still so many things to learn... Thanks Remy!

Answer (score 1):

Are we talking about visibility in code? If yes, then it is right that you see all properties as public, as published has the same visibility. The only difference between those two is that published properties are included in RTTI so they can be seen in the Object Inspector. But in code you can access public and published properties equally.

So if your first problem is from the coding side, this is correct behavior.

Regarding your second problem:

If you access the `Fields` property from a `TMyCustomComp` instance, you do not directly have an `SqlCommands` property, as you only have access to the `TFields` object, which inherits from `TCollection`. You first have to access one of the items, if neccessary cast it to `TFieldsItem` and then you can access its `SqlCommands` property.

In your `TCustomSqlCommands`, you already have those properties published, and in `TFieldsSqlCommands` you publish them again. I do not know if that is a problem, but maybe you can try making them public in `TCustomSqlCommands` and keep the published ones in `TFieldsSqlCommands`. However, you still should be able to access them all in code due to their visibility.

Comment: Now, after I see the Remy answer, I do understand your answer Serraniel ;)